# Most efficient way to query for login tries, checking IP as well as user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### The actual question

With performance in mind, how would you go about querying for username as well as IP adress in a single query (or several if more efficient ^^), given a login table like this (simplified):

```
login
------------------------------------------------------
LoginId     INT PRIMARY KEY
UserId      INT  (NULLABLE)
UserName    VARCHAR(100)
Status      ENUM('ERROR', 'SUCCESS', 'ATTEMPT', 'LOCKED')
IP          INT
Time        TIMESTAMP
```

### There are several thinks to take into account as far as I understand

#### Username

- Maximum number of tries for a specific UserName
- Locking this user via an Status `LOCKED` entry on his last try (instead of `ATTEMPT` otherwise)
- "Unlocking" him after a specific timespan
- Storing/Locking the actual entered Username instead of just the User ID - not giving a hint wether this user actually exists or not (primarily because in my case it is actually an email address instead)

#### IP

- Maximum number of tries from a single IP address
- Locking of the IP address only through timespan, not by setting a status (sufficient imho)
- (Not sure if this should be also "reset" on a succesful login from the IP - for now not considered)

#### Required Query Results

- The number of tries for this username, since the last successful login
- The number of tries from this IP within a specific time (lets say 5 minutes for simplicity)
- If - and more importantly - when the user was locked (he will be allowed to try again after some time)

This is my approach so far, if you have any suggestions/ideas how to do it better, easier, or more efficient, shoot :-)

For example I am not quite sure if it makes sense to lock the user for an hour, if he has tried 2 times some days ago, and now enters the wrong password for the 3rd time, but that is probably a different story.

### My query so far

```
SELECT 

       /* Count of login attempts for this user */
       COUNT(CASE WHEN UserName = ?  THEN 1  ELSE NULL END) AS LoginAttempts,

       /* When the user was locked or if at all */
       MAX(CASE WHEN Status='LOCKED' THEN Time  ELSE NULL END) AS UserLocked,

       /* Number of login attempts from this IP */
       (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM login 
           WHERE Status != 'SUCCESS' 
           AND   IP = INET_ATON(?)
           AND   Time > NOW()-INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AS GeneralAttemptsFromThisIP

WHERE 

       /* Filter attempts since last successful login */
       LoginId > (SELECT MAX(LoginId) FROM login WHERE UserName=? AND Status='SUCCESS')

       AND  UserName = ?

       AND  Status != 'SUCCESS'
```

Which is nothing more than two separate queries packed into one, with function calls in both `WHERE`s.

### Possible improvements

- Additional handling of IPv6
- Not just checking for `!='SUCCESS'` but specifically `ATTEMPT` and `LOCKED` (but since `ERROR` is reserved for very drastic cases - eg. hacking attempts - it should be of no consequence)
- Indexes (but no idea where to place them efficiently in this case, other than putting one multi-column for `UserName`, `Status` and possibly `Time`(?) (which would not help at all for the IP part though))

Comment: Just a couple of things to bear in mind about IP addresses. 1: They don't uniquely identify a user (not under IPv4 anyway) merely the router/firewall if it's a home or office network. 2: They're not entirely static even in a session - I've had load-balancing systems cause headaches before when the IP address for the user changed between sub-domains.

Comment: When I have done this in the passed (when checking for the user being logged in on page refreshes) I have done an update query, checking the fields (eg, userid, password, login tries) in the the WHERE clause. Then merely checked for the number of rows affected. With a count of attempts to log in you would need a 2nd query to update that with this method though.

Comment: @CD001: That is a really good thought! Would you say that IP checking should be left out totally, or just getting a really high number of possible tries?

Comment: @Kickstart: That might be an even better way, to update already while checking, since now I do that after evaluating the results from THIS query. The only drawback I could possibly see, is that in this way it might be easier for a locked user to clog the dbs (or not?), but it might be irrelevant since I am not really worring about (D)DoS yet, just safety and general performance.